# Load file and save file dialogs Xubuntu 16.04.1: How can I just enter the complete path instead of picking by mouse actions?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunderbird

I do not know how this happened and if it was there initally (but it is not long ago that I switched from Xubuntu 14.04 to 16.04), but currently I suffer from two flaws of Xubuntu 16.94.1, both regarding load file or save file dialogs:

**1.)** In most open file or a save file dialogs under Xubuntu 16.04.1, the file choosing dialog **shows me all files and directories sorted by name including hidden ones** (i.e. ones whose names begin with period) and **there is no distiction between files and directories**. It used to be "directories first". Even the operation Ctl+h does not exclude all hidden objects from the file chooser window! Among the affected applications: mousepad, gedit, parole, Thunderbird. Not affected: LibreOfficeWriter and Gimp (do they use another file choosing dialog?)

**2.)** The possibility to **directly type in the complete path from where to load or where to store is missing** for the programs mentioned above (and possibly more). Often I already have the complete path or very close to the place in the clipboard, e.g. after Ctl-C in a Thunar window which is already open close to where I want to load from or store to. In case my selection is not yet the right file name, I often first paste the complete path to a similar file in order to modify the name to fit my needs. This way I can easily place similar things close to each other and I can even afford file names which clearly tell what is in them.

Not necessary to mention that the loss of this property (it definetely was there for mousepad under Xubuntu 14.04. There it opened and in the left half of the screen the selection started with "last selection" (German: "Zuletzt verwendete"). As soon as you clicked onto one of the directories offered below that, a new text entry box opened labelled "Ort" in the German version and you could enter or paste the full file name into it.

Answer (score 0):

The syndrome went away as it came: I have no idea why it came nad no idea why it vanished. Of course I am happy that this bug does not continue to bother me.

In the meantime, of course, some system system actualizations have happened.

Although the root cause has not been identified, I mark this problem as solved hoping that neither myself nor anybody else will be further annoyed by it. But if it shows up again, maybe this thread gets reopened again.