# How do I make guis allow me to enter file path

Tags: firefox, xfce, chromium, 17.10

When selecting a file to attach to an e-mail in the browser (I use Gmail's web interface), I want to be able to quickly navigate in the "Open File"-like menus by first entering the full directory path, then clicking on the file.  Instead, I see a window that implies that I have to click through the directory structure.

I remember that the desired behavior was possible some time ago, but then the filepath field just disappeared from these windows.

If it matters, I use Xubuntu 17.10, the problem persists in both Firefox and Chromium.

There is a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936470/load-file-and-save-file-dialogs-xubuntu-16-04-1-how-can-i-just-enter-the-comple), but it has no answer as the issue of the OP just mysteriously solved itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Ctrl-L is what you are looking for. By default, I see a bar that looks something like this (when I am trying to attach a file from `/tmp`, for example):
[image: Screenshot by default]

After pressing Ctrl-L, I see this:
[image: Screenshot after Ctrl-L]